# Tensorflow: How to implement Multilayered dynamic_rnn?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I built a single-layered LSTM. It works.

The following code focus on the definition of weights and biases and RNN structure:

```
# Define weights
weights = {
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_inputs, n_hidden_units])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_units, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden_units, ])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_classes, ]))
}


def RNN(X, weights, biases):

    X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, n_inputs])

    X_in = tf.matmul(X, weights['in']) + biases['in']
    X_in = tf.reshape(X_in, [-1, n_steps, n_hidden_units])

    lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units)

    init_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size_holder, dtype=tf.float32)

    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, X_in, initial_state=init_state, time_major=False)

    outputs = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(outputs, [1,0,2]))
    results = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']    

        return results

pred = RNN(x, weights, biases) # prediction
```

Now, I want to add one more layer of LSTM cells. 
I checked the example on Tensorflow's official website.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent

But I had a hard time figuring out how MultiRNNCell can be used. I tried, using the same logic as common neural network, multiplying the output of the first layer and plus bias, then send to second layer. The following code implements this:

```
# Define weights
weights1 = {
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_inputs, n_hidden_units])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_units, n_hidden_units]))
}
biases1 = {
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden_units, ])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden_units, ]))
}

weights2 = {
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_inputs, n_hidden_units])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_units, n_classes]))
}
biases2 = {
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden_units, ])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_classes, ]))
}



def RNN(X, weights1, biases1, weights2, biases2):

    X = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_inputs])
    X_in = tf.matmul(X, weights1['in']) + biases1['in']
    X_in = tf.reshape(X_in, [-1, n_steps, n_hidden_units])

    lstm_cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units)
    lstm_cell2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units)

    init_state1 = lstm_cell1.zero_state(batch_size_holder, dtype=tf.float32)
    init_state2 = lstm_cell2.zero_state(batch_size_holder, dtype=tf.float32)

    outputs1, final_state1 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell1, X_in, initial_state=init_state1, time_major=False)

    outputs1 = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(outputs1, [1,0,2]))
    results1 = tf.matmul(outputs1[-1], weights1['out']) + biases1['out']    

    input = tf.matmul(results1, weights2['in']) + biases2['in']
    input = tf.reshape(input, [-1, n_steps, n_hidden_units])
    outputs2, final_state2 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell2, input, initial_state=init_state2, time_major=False)

    outputs2 = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(outputs2, [1,0,2]))
    results2 = tf.matmul(outputs2[-1], weights2['out']) + biases2['out']    


    return results2
```

I just make two layers of lstm_cells with equal sizes and call dynamic_rnn twice.

My first question is, is this code doing what I want?

When running, I got n error:

ValueError: Variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?

According to Tensorflow, (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent)
this is a version issue and should be solved by adding `reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse`
parameter to BasicLSTMCell().

However, my BasicLSTMCell() function don't even have "reuse" parameter.

Do you guys know how to make it work? Any advice and help are appreciated.

The full code is as follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf


lr = 0.005

n_inputs = 128
n_steps = 255
n_hidden_units = 128 
number_of_layers = 2
n_classes = 1      
batch_size = 100
gradient = 0.1

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
batch_size_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [], name='batch_size_holder')


# Define weights
weights = {
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_inputs, n_hidden_units])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_units, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden_units, ])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_classes, ]))
}


def RNN(X, weights, biases):

    X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, n_inputs])

    X_in = tf.matmul(X, weights['in']) + biases['in']
    X_in = tf.reshape(X_in, [-1, n_steps, n_hidden_units])

    lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units)

    init_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size_holder, dtype=tf.float32)

    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, X_in, initial_state=init_state, time_major=False)

    outputs = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(outputs, [1,0,2]))
    results = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']    # shape = (128, 10)

    return results


pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred-y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -gradient, gradient), var) for grad, var in gvs]
train_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gvs)

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

mydata = data(batch = batch_size, s = 10000, per = 0.95)
step = 0
train_loss = []
test_loss = []
while mydata.hasNext():
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mydata.next()
    batch_xs = batch_xs.reshape([batch_size, n_steps, n_inputs])
    batch_ys = batch_ys.reshape([batch_size, 1])

    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={
        x: batch_xs,
        y: batch_ys,
        batch_size_holder : 100
    })
    if step % 10 == 0:
        test_x, test_y = mydata.test()
        test_x = test_x.reshape([-1, n_steps, n_inputs])
        test_y = test_y.reshape([-1, 1])
        loss1 = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {x : batch_xs, y: batch_ys, batch_size_holder : 100})
        loss2 = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {x : test_x, y : test_y, batch_size_holder : 500})
        train_loss.append(loss1)
        test_loss.append(loss2)

        print("training cost: ", loss1)
        print("testing cost: ", loss2)
    step += 1

sess.close()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(train_loss)
plt.plot(test_loss)
```

**-------Update---------**

Thanks to vijay's answer, the updated code is as follow:

Note that the network has 2 (n_layers) LSTM layers, and 1 dense layer before outputting results.

```
import tensorflow as tf


lr = 0.01
n_inputs = 128
n_steps = 255
n_hidden_units = 200 
n_layers = 2
number_of_layers = 2
n_classes = 1
batch_size = 100
gradient = 0.5


# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
batch_size_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [], name='batch_size_holder')


def lstm_cell():        
    return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units)

def RNN(X):

    lstm_stacked = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(n_layers)]) 
    init_state = lstm_stacked.zero_state(batch_size_holder, dtype=tf.float32)
    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_stacked, X, dtype=tf.float32)

    output = tf.layers.dense(outputs[:, -1, :], 1)

    return output


pred = RNN(x)
cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, pred)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -gradient, gradient), var) for grad, var in gvs]
train_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gvs)

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

mydata = data(batch = batch_size, s = 30000, per = 0.95)
step = 0
train_loss = []
test_loss = []
while mydata.hasNext():
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mydata.next()
    batch_xs = batch_xs.reshape([batch_size, n_steps, n_inputs])
    batch_ys = batch_ys.reshape([batch_size, 1])

    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={
        x: batch_xs,
        y: batch_ys,
        batch_size_holder : batch_size
    })
    if step % 10 == 0:
        test_x, test_y = mydata.test()
        test_x = test_x.reshape([-1, n_steps, n_inputs])
        test_y = test_y.reshape([-1, 1])
        loss1 = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {x : batch_xs, y: batch_ys, batch_size_holder : batch_size})
        loss2 = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {x : test_x, y : test_y, batch_size_holder : 1500})
        train_loss.append(loss1)
        test_loss.append(loss2)

        print("training cost: ", loss1, "testing cost: ", loss2)

    step += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a `multi-layer LSTM` you can use `tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell`. So for a two layer:

```
n_layers = 2
lstm_stacked = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(n_layers)]) 
outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_stacked, X_in, dtype=tf.float32)

def lstm_cell():        
    # Single RNN cell
    return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units)
```

Comment: Can't  believe it's that simple! So how do I set weight, bias and initial state for each layers? How to run dynamic_rnn?

Comment: bias, weights are handled by the functions internally, if you want to pass the initial state, you can use the param in dynamic_rnn.  The above code includes the `dynamic_rnn` call.

Comment: So, in my original code, the definition of weights and biases are not necessary and wrong? I shouldn't do `X_in = tf.matmul(X, weights['in']) + biases['in']` ?
`# Define weights
weights = {
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_inputs, n_hidden_units])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_units, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden_units, ])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_classes, ]))
}

`

Comment: Oh ok,  you are talking about dense layer before the LSTM layer, yes its the same way  you  have done before.